# How to change Sprite texture to Animation

Tags: java, animation, libgdx, sprite

I have a Sprite that spawns every second, what I wan't to do is change the sprite texture to animation, and the when it's touched it will be back to a normal texture.

```
     public void draw(SpriteBatch batch){
       enemyIterator=enemies.iterator();  //arraylist iterator
       boolean touched=Gdx.input.justTouched();
       float touchX=Gdx.input.getX();

   //rendering and making the current sprite move
       while(enemyIterator.hasNext()){
           Sprite sprite=enemyIterator.next();
           sprite.draw(batch);
           sprite.translateY(deltaTime*movement);

//detecting if the screen is touched and if the inputX is inside of the sprite.
           if(touched==true && touchX > sprite.getX() && touchX < sprite.getX()+sprite.getWidth()){
               enemyIterator.remove(); //removing the sprite when touched.
               Pools.free(sprite); //freeing the Pools
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

**To change from a texture to an animation**

Create a subclas of Sprite called MySprite or something, and override the `draw(batch)` method.

In the overriden draw method, if you want to draw a texture, simply call `super.draw(batch)`, otehrwise use your animation draw code. You can get the delta time using `Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()`

**Why you have to specify timePassed**

Your program will run at different frame rates to the animation, so by telling the animation how much time has passed, it can work out what frame it should be on according to it's own framerate.

Note that the framerate of your app can vary from frame-to-frame depending on how much work it has to do.